# library(e1071), tune Variable lengths differ

Tags: r, svm

I have been attempting to utilize the `iris` dataset and although I've gotten `svm` to work from the `e1071` library, I keep getting a 'variable lengths differ' error when I attempt to make `tune` work:

```
library(e1071)  

data <- data.frame(iris$Sepal.Width,iris$Petal.Length,iris$Species)
svm_tr <- data[sample(nrow(datasvm), 100), ] #sample 100 random rows

tuned <- tune(svm, svm_tr$iris.Species~.,
              data = svm_tr[1:2],
              kernel = "linear",
              ranges = list(cost=c(.001,.01,.1,1,10,100)))
```

I have checked the lengths of each of the columns in `svm_tr[1:2]` and they are the same length.  I know the function doesn't take a dataframe directly but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Your second line creates the variable `data` but your third line uses `datasvm` Are they the same thing?

Comment: just repaired - yes.

Comment: I can get it to work with `tune(svm, iris.Species ~ ., data = svm_tr[1:3], kernel = "linear", ranges = list(cost=c(.001,.01,.1,1,10,100)))` - if it's a formula interface you shouldn't be referring to a variable by using `$`. Note that I've also made `data=svm_tr[1:3]` instead of `1:2` so that the `iris.Species` column is found.

Comment: Yes - this worked! Yeah, I only had it `1:2` b/c I read on another answer that it wouldn't work with a straight dataframe - the issue was likely the `$` in the formula interface. Further, I've removed the `[1:3]` because the dataframe works directly now.  Thank you, @thelatemail !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get it to work with:

```
tune(svm, iris.Species ~ ., data = svm_tr[1:3],
     kernel = "linear", ranges = list(cost=c(.001,.01,.1,1,10,100)))
```

If it's a formula interface you shouldn't be referring to a variable by using `$` as all the required variables are sourced from the object specified by the `data=` argument. Note that I've also made `data=svm_tr[1:3]` instead of `1:2` so that the `iris.Species` column is included.

Comment: This was it! Thank you!